# Перевод wiki и связанных с ним вещей

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Как будем переводить `community wiki` и связанные с ним термины? В [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21564/stack-overflow-in-russian-translation) разгорелась нешуточная дискуссия.

- Community wiki?
- Community wiki post?
- Community wiki status (of a post)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

- community wiki = общие вопросы/ответы
- wiki post = общий вопрос/ответ
- converted to wiki = сделан общим

---

Остальные варианты

- Вариант 1.

  - community wiki = совместно редактируемые вопросы/ответы
  - wiki post = вики- вопрос/ответ
  - converted to wiki = преобразован в вики- вопрос/ответ
- Вариант 2.

  - community wiki = вики
  - wiki post = вики-сообщение/вопрос/ответ
  - converted to wiki = Преобразован в вики-вопрос/ответ
- Вариант 3.

  - community wiki = общественное достояние
  - wiki post = сообщение из общественного достояния
  - converted to wiki = отдан в общественное достояние
- Вариант 4.

  - community wiki = совместно редактируемые вопросы
  - wiki post = сообщение сообщества
  - converted to community wiki = сделан общим
- Вариант 5.

  - community wiki = wiki
  - wiki post = wiki-сообщение/вопрос/ответ
  - converted to wiki = Преобразован в wiki-вопрос/ответ